# gensim CoherenceModel gives "ValueError: unable to interpret topic as either a list of tokens or a list of ids"

Tags: python, text-mining, gensim, topic-modeling

I was trying to tune the hyperparameters min_topic_size and top_n_words for my BERTopic topic models. I kept running against the error ""ValueError: unable to interpret topic as either a list of tokens or a list of ids" when evaluating a certain set of values for the parameters. Some pairs of values seem to work fine, while some don't. For instance, when `min_topic_size =20` and `top_n_word=5`, it just failed to give the score. While some other time with different values, it worked.The text file i used is here [abs text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xCD3JJVoS_EDDntsJaq6fYltqOnukArL/view?usp=sharing).

I have no clue what seems to be an issue here.

```
from bertopic import BERtopic 
from umap import UMAP
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel


umap_model = UMAP(n_neighbors=15, n_components=5, 
                  min_dist=0.5, metric='cosine', random_state=42)
abs=df.abstract.to_list()
yr=df.year.to_list()

#Hyperparametre tuning : top_n_words and min_topic_size 

def bert_coh(model,docs):
    score=[]
    cleaned_docs=model._preprocess_text(docs)
    vectorizer=model.vectorizer_model
    tokenizer = vectorizer.build_tokenizer()
    words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    tokens=[tokenizer(doc) for doc in cleaned_docs]
    dictionary =corpora.Dictionary(tokens)
    corpus=[dictionary.doc2bow(token) for token in tokens]
    topic_words = [[words for words, _ in model.get_topic(topic)] 
               for topic in range(len(set(topics))-1)]
    uci = CoherenceModel(topics=topic_words, 
                                 texts=tokens, 
                                 corpus=corpus,
                                 dictionary=dictionary, 
                                 coherence='c_uci')
    umass= CoherenceModel(topics=topic_words, 
                                 texts=tokens, 
                                 corpus=corpus,
                                 dictionary=dictionary, 
                                 coherence='u_mass')
    npmi = CoherenceModel(topics=topic_words, 
                                 texts=tokens, 
                                 corpus=corpus,
                                 dictionary=dictionary, 
                                 coherence='c_npmi')
    for obj in (uci,umass,npmi):
        coherence = obj.get_coherence()
        score.append(coherence)
    return score
#training model
#use abs at the abs text file 
model=BERTopic(top_n_words=5,umap_model=umap_model,min_topic_size=20,calculate_probabilities=True,
                          n_gram_range=(1,3),low_memory=True,verbose=True,language='multilingual')
topics,_ =model.fit_transforms(abs) 
bert_coh(model,abs)
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

- Use the build_analyzer() instead of build_tokenizer() which allows for n-gram
  tokenization
- Preprocessing is now based on a collection of documents per topic, since the
  CountVectorizer was trained on that data

  ```
   from bertopic import BERTopic
   import gensim.corpora as corpora
   from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel

   topic_model = BERTopic(verbose=True, n_gram_range=(1, 3))
   topics, _ = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)

   # Preprocess Documents
   documents_per_topic = documents.groupby(['Topic'], as_index=False).agg({'Document': ' '.join})
   cleaned_docs = topic_model._preprocess_text(documents_per_topic.Document.values)

   # Extract vectorizer and analyzer from BERTopic
   vectorizer = topic_model.vectorizer_model
   analyzer = vectorizer.build_analyzer()

   # Extract features for Topic Coherence evaluation
   words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
   tokens = [analyzer(doc) for doc in cleaned_docs]
   dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokens)
   corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(token) for token in tokens]
   topic_words = [[words for words, _ in topic_model.get_topic(topic)] 
              for topic in range(len(set(topics))-1)]

   # Evaluate
   coherence_model = CoherenceModel(topics=topic_words, 
                                texts=tokens, 
                                corpus=corpus,
                                dictionary=dictionary, 
                                coherence='c_v')
   coherence = coherence_model.get_coherence()
  ```

For more issues about Coherence of topic models refer this [link](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/issues/90)